# How can I create the dynamic table beautifully?

Tags: html, ruby, html-table

How can I set the table tag like this?

> ```
>           col1  col2  col3 col4
>          _____ _____ _____ _____
>  row1   |     |_____|_____|     |
>  row2   |     |_____|_____|     |
>  row3   |     |_____|_____|     |
>  row4   |_____|_____|_____|_____|
> ```

I know use the attribute `rowspan`to let the layout like this

as following my code:

```
  <table>
  <tr>
    <th>number</th>
    <th>type</th>
    <th>quantity</th>
    <th>amount</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="5">a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td rowspan="5">d</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But in my case, the code is in the iterator of ruby `each do` method.
the items of col1 are all same, but items of col2 and col3 are all dynamic and col4 is the result of col3 calculating(sum).

I used to stupid way to layout the col1 by repeating the same value from row1 to row4 like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>number</th>
    <th>type</th>
    <th>quantity</th>
    <th>amount</th>
  </tr>
  <%@deals.each do |staff, deals|%>
    <%if staff%>
    <% @total_deal_type = deals.group_by(&:type).count%>
      <%deals.group_by(&:type).each do |type, deals|%>
      <tr>
        <td><%=staff.number%></td>
        <%case type%>
          <%when "service1"%>
          <%@d=staff.service1*deals.count%>

            <td><%=type%></td>
            <td><%= deals.count%></td>


          <%when "service2"%>
          <%@d2=staff.service2*deals.count%>

            <td><%=type%></td>
            <td><%= deals.count%></td>


          <%when "service3"%>
          <%@nc=staff.service3*deals.count%>

            <td><%=type%></td>
            <td><%= deals.count%></td>


          <%when "service4"%>
          <%@add=staff.service4*deals.count%>

            <td><%=type%></td>
            <td><%= deals.count%></td>


          <%when "service5"%>
          <%@bh=staff.service5*deals.count%>

            <td><%=type%></td>
            <td><%= deals.count%></td>

        <%end%>
      </tr>

      <%end%>
      <!--<p>amount:<%=@d.to_i+@d2.to_i+@nc.to_i+@add.to_i+@bh.to_i%></p>-->

    <%end%>

  <%end%>

</table>
```

So I want to merge the same value.

It's some way to do this?

Comment: Add the ruby code to this question, please.

Comment: @ThisClark I add some code in this editing thanks